# How to get only the mismatched columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

while comparing two csv files, I want to export the only columns which has mismatch.Below code gives me all the columns, not the mismatch column, in this case only email, profession column has
the mismatch values between 2 dataframes. How to export only mismatch columns?

```
import pandas as pa
df1 = pa.read_csv('data1.csv')
df2 = pa.read_csv('data2.csv')
diff =df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,how='outer')
diff1 = diff[diff['_merge'] == 'left_only']
print(diff1)
```

Below is the output

```
    id firstname lastname  ...                     email2      profession     _merge
1  101  Gilligan    Brenn  ...   Gilligan.Brenn@gmail.com          worker  left_only
8  108   Sherrie   Ventre  ...   Sherrie.Ventre@gmail.com  police officer  left_only
9  109  Roseline   Roscoe  ...  Roseline.Roscoe@gmail.com       developer  left_only
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [pandas.Dataframe.ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html), like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pa.read_csv('data1.csv')
df2 = pa.read_csv('data2.csv')

diffs = (
    df2[df2.ne(df1)]
    .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
    .dropna(axis=0, how="all")
    .fillna("")
)

print(diffs)
# Outputs
                     email2   profession
1  Gilligan.Brenn@gmail.com
8                             worker
9  Roseline.Roscoe@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks. but lets say in future other column i am getting mismatch, how do i handle. here we explicitly mention email2, i need it should be dynamic